# Get select element by selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a way to get a select element using it's selected value.
It's easy for options : `$('option[value="lol"]');`

But it's not working with `$('select[value="lol"]');`

Is it possible to do this with a simple selector ?

Comment: if( document.getElementsByTagName("select").value=="lol") did not work?

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].value=="lol"` , `getElementsByTagName` return an array

Comment: This tells me if the value is lol, but what I needed is a short function that  would return the select without custom loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)?

```
$("select").filter(function() {
    return $(this).val() === "lol";
});
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/f2dvvdj0/)

This is assuming you want all `<select>` elements where the `lol` option is actually selected. If you just wanted to check to see if the select contains the `lol` option, selected or not, you can use parent:

```
$('option[value="lol"]').parent();
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/pz4szo0q/)

Comment: I like your solutions, what i needed was in fact a mix of both :)
$('option[value="lol"]:selected').parent();
Thanks

Comment: That's a very good solution, in fact you might even consider adding that as an answer yourself as it answers your question better than my answer does.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this in jQuery:

```js
var lol = getSelect(1);

lol.css({
  "color": "red"
});


function getSelect(i) {
  var option = $('select option[value="' + i + '"]');
  return option.parent('select');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselect">
    <option value="1">Mr</option>
    <option value="2">Mrs</option>
    <option value="3">Ms</option>
    <option value="4">Dr</option>
    <option value="5">Prof</option>
</select>
```